# How to use React with Bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am learning React, and I want to make my first project using Bootstrap also. I followed [this tutorial](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-use-bootstrap-with-react-a354715d1121), but all I get is this error:

```
./src/App.js
  Line 9:  'Jumbotron' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef
```

This is my `Apps.js`:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Jumbotron>
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to My First React project</h1>
        </header>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
      </Jumbotron>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

This is my `index.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

And this is my `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">

    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">

    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

I installed all the modules stated in the tutorial and made the `imports`, but compiler still don't recognize **Bootstrap** objects, like `Jumbotron`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're referencing a global variable that doesn't exist. you're looking for https://reactstrap.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

In this case, since you are importing the boostrap css file, you need to use the 'jumbotron' as a class in a div.

If you wanna write the bootstrap elements as jsx tags like you did you need to use the library Andy Ray referenced.